# WinRT XAML Databinding: How to bind to a property to the parent's data context when binding within an ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a **GridView** for which I set the data context programmatically to the view model instance.
The **GridView's ItemsSource** is bound to an observable collection (PagesToRead) which is a property on the view model.

Within the **GridView.ItemTemplate**, binding goes against the observable collection in the **ItemsSource**, but I want to bind the StackPanel's **Background** element to a different property on the view model.

I'm looking for the magic `<Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, Source=???}">` that will escape the current ItemsSource and bind to the **BackgroundColor** property on the view model.

Here's the elided XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <GridView x:Name="MainGrid" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PagesToRead}"
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate >
          <StackPanel>
            <Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, Source=???}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" 
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
  </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer via another avenue (thanks Karl Erickson). What you do is:

```
<StackPanel Background="{Binding Path=DataContext.TileBackgroundColor,
                         ElementName=MainGrid">
```

Comment: This won't work for me because my DataTemplate is in a separate xaml file and is used in more than one parent.